# Implicações de @Autowired em construtor e fora

Tags: java, spring

Ao trabalhar com Spring percebo dois padrões de utilizar o *@Autowired*, declarar dentro do construtor e fora.

Construtor

```
@Service
public class myService { 
    private final PartnerRepository partnerRepository;
    private final RequestorRepository requestorRepository;

    @Autowired
    public myService(PartnerRepository partnerRepository, RequestorRepository requestorRepository) {
        this.partnerRepository = partnerRepository;
        this.requestorRepository = requestorRepository;
    }
```

Sem construtor

```
@Service
public class myService { 
        @Autowired
        PartnerRepository partnerRepository;
        @Autowired 
        RequestorRepository requestorRepository;

        //methods
}
```

Qual a utilidade de cada um dos casos e por quê preferir um ao invés do outro? Pessoalmente sempre utilizei fora do construtor **apenas** parecer mais elegante.

A única implicação direta que percebi foi para testes unitários com Mockito e JUnit, ao utilizar fora do construtor é necessário utilizar *@Spy* (resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270391/mockito-inject-real-objects-into-private-autowired-fields)) e ao utilizar no construtor é possível fazer uma instanciação direta com o *new*.

```
 MyService myService = Mockito.spy(new MyService(partnerRepository, requestorRepository));
```

Comment: Há uma terceira forma também, pode utilizar o `@Autowired` em um setter

Answer (score 0):

Todas as formas servem para o mesmo objetivo, e se obtém o mesmo resultado final.
A vantagem de ser no construtor é:

- Identificar explicitamente quais as dependências
- As dependências podem ser *final*
- Facilita na criação de testes. Fica mais fácil injetar mocks, você pode fazer isso usando o próprio construtor da classe, não necessitando de reflexão.

Usar um ou outro fica na sua escolha.